# Needs and this.get('controllers') give wrong results when used with outlet in partial view?

Tags: ember.js

Hi and thanks a lot for your precious help on this problem.

As I am quite new in EmberJS' world, problem may come from me and not Ember, but I don't find the right way to fix it.

I have a template named a, a view named AAView (with its template, too) and two controllers AAController and BController.

Template 'a' is rendered by using partial method :

{{partial 'a'}}

AAController is controller for AAView, connected to AAOutlet which is in 'a' template with

```
this.render('aa', {
    outlet: 'AAOutlet',
    into: 'application'
});
```

In this AAView, I have an observer that **should** observes *isShown* property of AAController.

```
App.AAView = Ember.View.extend({
    visibilityDidChanged: function() {
        console.log('Visibility just changed man! Do something!');
    }.observes('controller.isShown')
});
```

This *isShown* variable is in AAController then...

```
App.AAController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    isShown: false
});
```

And this variable is set in an other controller (BController) :

```
App.BController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    needs: ['AA'],
    myVal: '', 
    myValDidChanged:function() {
        //Conditions and a lot of interesting stuffs
        this.get('controllers.AA').set('isShown', true);
    }.observes('myVal')
});
```

When my script is executed and reach this code, the view is **not notified** about the change in controller...

If I stop debugger on *this.get('controllers.AA').set('isShown', true);* line, it seems that *this.get('controllers.AA')* returns an other (or a new ?) controller and not the controller used and observed by the view.

Thus where is the problem and how can I retrieve the right controller in BController to edit the value and trigger the observer in the view ?

**[--> Here is a jsFiddle with a simplified version of the problem.](http://jsfiddle.net/x6emd/1/)**

Huge thanks for your help on this one!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

xpost from https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/3404

@Gerfaut There are several points of confusion here.

Among them is using "AAController" as a name- this causes some serious mis-direction. When you render into the outlet with:

```
this.render('aa', ...
```

`AaController` will be resolved, not `AAController`. The same goes for `AAView`, it was not hooked up to the UI at all. `AaView` was instead wired in.

Take a look at: http://jsfiddle.net/x6emd/3/ which resolves your issues by using the correct naming scheme.

I recommend using:

```
window.App = Ember.Application.create({
  LOG_TRANSITIONS: true, // basic logging of successful transitions
  LOG_VIEW_LOOKUPS: true,
  LOG_ACTIVE_GENERATION: true
});
```

To help you debug naming issues.

Comment: Thanks again for your help, here and on Github!

Answer (score 0):

When controllers are instantiated by Ember they are assigned a name that begins with a lowercase letter. This is consistent with Ember naming conventions. Try this.get('controllers.a').

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work either ...
I wanted to make a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6emd/) very simple to explain my problem and there, of course, everything works!
I think I'll have to keep looking through my code which might break the operation ...
Unless someone has an idea or has encountered a similar problem?

Comment: Hi, I updated my jsFiddle and was able to reproduce the problem. It seems to happen when using an outlet in a partial view...
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: Even with nested outlets, it is not working : http://jsfiddle.net/x6emd/2/? Is this usecase not supported?